# Adding Placeholder To Input Field By Name

Tags: javascript, placeholder, getelementsbyname

I'm trying to add a placeholder to an an attribute using JavaScript.

The Input element's HTML is:

```
<td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_72_cell3" data-label="Amount Paid">
<input type="text" name="input_72[]" value="" tabindex="67">
</td>
```

Seems I need to target it by the class also of the parent td "gfield_list_cell gfield_list_72_cell3"

I'm trying to target this using Javascript and a $ sign as the placeholder. I'm using this, but can't get it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var input = document.getElementsByName('input_72[]')[0];
  input.setAttribute('placeholder', '$');
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  use `querySelector` method.

```js
document.querySelector('.gfield_list_cell.gfield_list_72_cell3 input').setAttribute('placeholder','$');
```

```html
<table>
<td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_72_cell3" data-label="Amount Paid">
       <input type="text" name="input_72[]" value="" tabindex="67">
</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var input = document.getElementsByName('input_72[]')[0];
input.setAttribute('placeholder', '$');
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. @downvoter, please explain this.

Comment: Hi Alexandru, I don't see how this would target just input_72[]

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai - It works but it it does not target the correct input field.  I need to target the input field inside "gfield_list_cell gfield_list_72_cell3"

Comment: @AlanCarr, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(input[name="input_72[]"]).setAttr('placeholder', '$');
```

use jquery to add placeholder dynamically

Answer (score -2):

No need to using javascript simply add placeholder in input.

```
<input type="text" name="input_72[]" value="" tabindex="67" placeholder="Name">
```